# Hibernate can not find PostgreSQL sequence

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am working on a Spring Boot Project. I have the following entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "author_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "author_seq", 
        sequenceName = "authors_authorid_seq", schema = "public")
    private int authorid;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    
    public Author() {
    }

    public int getAuthorid() {
        return authorid;
    }

    public void setAuthorid(int authorid) {
        this.authorid = authorid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    
}
```

I have the following sequences in database :

`authors_authorid_seq`
`bookborrow_id_seq`
`books_bookid_seq`
`users_userid_seq`

I am getting the following error :

`org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [public.authors_authorid_seq]`

Can you please help me about what I am doing wrong? My Hibernate version is 5.4.25. Thanks

Comment: in wich schema your squence was created , could you show a view of pg here

Comment: here is the view from DBeaver [link](https://ibb.co/H2t7qPM). It is in the public schema. Another strange thing is PgAdmin4 does not show the sequences, but it also does not allow to create sequences with aforementioned names, it says relation with that name already exists.

Comment: I found the solution, if anyone is interested I am writing it here : I solved the problem by manually creating sequences in init_db.sql script. In previous version, which caused the error, I was creating the primary key that caused the error like this :
`authorid int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY`
This automatically creates a sequence, but PgAdmin4 and Hibernate libraries was not able to detect it.
Now I create the primary key column like this :
`authorid int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('authors_authorid_seq')`. This way hibernate can detect sequences.

Comment: great post it as answer , may be it'll help others

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by manually creating sequences in init_db.sql script.

In previous version, which caused the error, I was creating the primary key that caused the error like this :

```
authorid int4 NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
```

This automatically creates a sequence, but PgAdmin4 and Hibernate libraries was not able to detect it.

Now I create the primary key column like this :

```
authorid int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('authors_authorid_seq').
```

This way hibernate can detect sequences.